# Running ipython notebook in a Docker Container

Tags: docker, containers, jupyter-notebook

Can someone share the steps to run iPython notebook in a container.

I tried to run *ipython notebook* command in my ubuntu 14.04 container shell. The only problem is that it **can not find a web browser** to open on,  since containers only work for service applications instead of interactive ones.

Any suggestions?

Comment: iff you take https://hub.docker.com/r/jess/ipython-notebook/ and add firefox in the various softs installed?

Comment: @user2915097, the link you provided is broken.

Comment: Yes several months later, that can happen

Comment: @madhavi, I just provided an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start the container, you can specify port forwarding via the -p option. For example, run:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 mxnet/python bash
```

Then when starting the notebook, specify the port:

```
ipython notebook --port=8888 --no-browser --ip='*' &
```

Then navigate to the appropriate IP in your browser (typically localhost or 127.0.0.1).

Comment: mxnet/python launches a container with python3.5 installed. So a pretty old version.

Answer (score 2):

There are two images provided by [Ananconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) originally called Continuum Analytics.

The answer I am providing assumes you need to run a notebook using a container based on the `anaconda3` image, but you can also use the `miniconda3` image instead. You can see the differences between both in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421163/anaconda-vs-miniconda).

You can run the following commands in order to have a jupyter notebook running from a container:

```
$ docker pull continuumio/anaconda3
$ docker run -it -p 8888:8888 continuumio/anaconda3 bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && mkdir /opt/notebooks && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser --allow-root"
```

Alternatively, you can also just run the container and open the bash by:

```
$ docker run -it continuumio/anaconda3 bash
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/jfrazelle/dockerfiles/blob/master/ipython-notebook/notebook.sh. I think you can run with `--no-browser`

```
ipython notebook --no-browser
```

Comment: I wanted to port map it to the host machine. Is that possible?

Comment: @dnephin, the link you provided is broken.