# jupyter notebook not recognized in fresh miniconda3 instalation

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, miniconda

I installed fresh miniconda3, from here: https://conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

when opening anaconda prompt, python works correctly, but `jupyter notebook` gives the following error:

```
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

 where conda
```

show:

```
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
```

All the answers I found talk about PATH.
but, I don't see `jupyter.exe` at all.
In the past, miniconda installation came with jupyter notebook.
Was it changed ? do I need to install it separately ?

```
conda list
```

outputs:

```
# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0
certifi                   2018.11.29               py37_0
cffi                      1.11.5           py37h74b6da3_1
chardet                   3.0.4                    py37_1
conda                     4.5.12                   py37_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         3
cryptography              2.4.2            py37h7a1dbc1_0
idna                      2.8                      py37_0
menuinst                  1.4.14           py37hfa6e2cd_0
openssl                   1.1.1a               he774522_0
pip                       18.1                     py37_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
pyopenssl                 18.0.0                   py37_0
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py37_0
python                    3.7.1                h8c8aaf0_6
pywin32                   223              py37hfa6e2cd_1
requests                  2.21.0                   py37_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py37hfa6e2cd_0
setuptools                40.6.3                   py37_0
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0
sqlite                    3.26.0               he774522_0
urllib3                   1.24.1                   py37_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_0
wheel                     0.32.3                   py37_0
win_inet_pton             1.0.1                    py37_1
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since Miniconda is just an installer for an empty Conda environment (well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421163/anaconda-vs-miniconda)), it basically contains only Python itself, Conda and its dependencies, as you can see in your `conda list`, so you need to install all other packages from scratch. It says so in the documentation you posted as well :)

> These Miniconda installers contain the conda package manager and Python.

`Jupyter notebook` is included in the Anaconda installation, but not in Miniconda.

To answer your question: yes, you will need to run `conda install jupyter`. I hope that helps!