# Can I delete the packages in the Anaconda root environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I recently discovered you can add more environments in Anaconda, e.g. through the Anaconda Navigator -> Environments tab - > Create.
The advantage is that it lets you always go to the highest version of package eg.

```
pd.__version__, np.__version__, numba.__version__
('1.0.3', '1.18.1', '0.48.0')
```

vs the base/root environment which is limited by the Anaconda dependencies

```
pd.__version__, np.__version__, numba.__version__
('0.25.1', '1.17.2', '0.45.1')
```

Another advantage is I can be much more selective in the packages, out of the box a new environment comes with much less,  in my case **91** incl. what I installed  vs **305** on root

**->** So who needs all that "bloatware" on the root environment? Can I just delete all of those packages, and if so, how to do that efficiently?

Side note: I know about miniconda but I may not be ready to switch yet.

Comment: _So who needs all that “bloatware” on the root environment?_ Are you referring to the packages which are there by default, or those that you added?

Comment: those that came with the default install. 100s. Out of the 305 I maybe added 3 or 4

Comment: The base environment includes hundreds of packages by default? I recently switched to Miniconda, so I unfortunately can’t check right now, but it’s certainly possible that I might have just never noticed the amount of packages. In any case, why would you want to delete them (and what do you mean by delete) ?

Comment: They take up a ton of space for starters, and I never use any of them but a few - less than 10. And they are often not fully up to date. So I will only use my new environment and don't need anything on root. I heard of miniconda but I feel I am not savvy enough yet for that.

Comment: I don know all the inner workings of conda, the commands etc. And according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421163/anaconda-vs-miniconda Anaconda is for people new to Python.

Comment: Important question: What do you mean by _delete all those packages_ ? Do you want them removed from the base env, or removed from your computer entirely?

Comment: I think we should take this to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210310/discussion-between-amc-and-disc-o).