# mini conda vs anaconda - installing environments best practice question

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I'm new to miniconda and anaconda. I just wanted to get an opinion on anaconda vs miniconda in the hope of finding out what's better for my needs.

Currently i've got miniconda installed and everytime I want to work on a project I have to create a new environment inside a project folder.

Before I download and intall it I wanted to know whether if I install it, whether I would have to create an environment for each project, or will they all work at a system level.

If I have to create an environment even in anaconda, then there's no point me installing it as well.

Thanks.

Comment: anaconda is just miniconda with a wide range of scientific packages preinstalled. There's no difference than that AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

*Currently i've got miniconda installed and everytime I want to work on a project I have to create a new environment inside a project folder.* Yes, that's basically one of the two functions of Conda, it's a good thing.

*Before I download and intall it I wanted to know whether if I install it, whether I would have to create an environment for each project, or will they all work at a system level.* That sounds like a bad idea!

*If I have to create an environment even in anaconda, then there's no point me installing it as well.* What is the point of using Conda, rather?

Take a look at some of the questions with the `anaconda` and `conda` tags, there are mountains of people encountering issues which stem from using a single environment for  everything.

As for the question of Miniconda vs Anaconda, I stick to using the former, and get all my packages from the popular [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org) channel.

Comment: Quick follow up question! When installing packages that are not on the base version, is it better to install it on base and the project environment, or just the project environment? 

My thinking is this: install it on base and the recreate the environment. This way the packages will be there for any future projects.