# Multiple files in Anaconda folder

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda

Recently i have installed Anaconda 3 to use Jupyter Notebook for Machine Learning. Here in Anaconda I found there are multiple packages(some called it as module) at different locations in which some are duplicate.

Location 1: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs`

Location 2: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib`

Location 3: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages`(My custom Environment for Machine learning Programs which includes scikit-learn, pandas, etc...)

So is there a way I can combine this all and add to myenv(custom environment)? and delete `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs` this folder?

Comment: This should indirectly answer your question: [Why are packages installed rather than just linked to a specific environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566419/why-are-packages-installed-rather-than-just-linked-to-a-specific-environment) Namely, it's hardlinking anyway, so don't sweat it - they're not actual copies. It you are space constrained, instead try installing [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) and install only the packages you need.

Answer (score 1):

You just don't understand what `conda` is and how it works. Here is a [brief introduction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58112484/5101148).

- `pkgs` is the default cache directory for package installed by you.
- `Lib` stores libraries for the base/root environment, this is the very environment makes `conda` work
- `envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages`, user-installed packages for specific environment `myenv`