# Can I move Python's install directory anywhere (is it portable)?

Tags: python

Let's say I don't want to access this python installation from PATH or `py` on the console, just call on the python.exe file directly. In that case, can I copy the python installation directory into an app folder for something I'm developing to have essentially a portable python packaged with my app?

Comment: It looks like you're after [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. But there is a concept in Python called virtual environments that you should take a look at. The idea is to seperate a project environment from the one on your operating system. It's the recommended way for developing python applications as you can have multiple different environments depending on your projects requirements.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

You can also take a look at Conda. Its a more user friendly way of using Environments (in my opinion). If you are interested in Conda you can also look at that question for more information about the differences of Miniconda and Anaconda: [Anaconda vs. miniconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421163/anaconda-vs-miniconda)

Installation of Conda: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/windows.html