# How can a pre-built Python-installation be modified to work in another directory?

Tags: python, pip, distutils

For a project shipping with a pre-built customized Python distribution I need to be able to compile packages from source using `pip` (within the installed environment).

This is what the file system structure for two installations of the final product might look like:

```
/opt
├── my-program-v1
│   ├── some-files
│   ├── custom-python-3.9
├── my-program-v2
│   ├── some-files
│   ├── custom-python-3.11
```

Since the readily installed program (together with its Python installation) might be installed to any directory, `pip` needs a way to find the header files for the used Python installation.

Just copying the whole Python installation to the desired directory will result in errors when trying to `pip install` a package that needs to be built from source (e.g. `ibm_db`):

```
$ python3 -m pip install ibm_db
Collecting ibm_db
  Downloading ibm_db-3.1.4.tar.gz (1.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.4/1.4 MB 9.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Detected 64-bit Python
      Detected platform = linux, uname = x86_64
      Downloading https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/linuxx64_odbc_cli.tar.gz
       Downloading DSDriver from url =  https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/linuxx64_odbc_cli.tar.gz
      Pre-requisite check [gcc] : Passed
      
      No Python.h header file detected.
      Please install python-devel or python3-devel as instructed in "https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/blob/master/README.md#KnownIssues" and continue with the installation
      [end of output]
```

Usually, when you build Python from source you would set the final destination folder using `configure --prefix=/opt/my-program-v2`, which would be stored inside the sysconfigdata of that readily built Python installation.

But how can this be done when you need to pre-build Python and don't know the installation directory in advance?

One possible way is to manually modify the generated sysconfig-data, (usually found in `lib/<python-version>/_sysconfigdata__linux_x86_64-linux-gnu.py`) but this is not fun (due to the used format) and introduces a step outside of the CI.

How do others do that? Is there an intended way to place/relocate a prebuilt installation of python?

Comment: Related – [Can I move Python's install directory anywhere (is it portable)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68144151/95735)

Comment: This is a follow up to [Is there an way to reconfigure `_sysconfigdata.py` or to let it contain dynamic values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74876162/95735)

Comment: Chronologically yes, semantically it's the other way round :)

Comment: That is right, indeed.